# I want to cover a circular area with a sheet that is rolled onto a curved metal rod

Tags: mechanical, architecture

My challenge is that the sheet gets bent in places around the rod making extension challenging. Another challenge is that since the metal rod is curved it turns in an awkward way that I want to minimise, ie the ends traverse a circle in space. My thought is to use another rod within the cylinder which ball bearings that touch the inner layers so that and rotational force gets transferred to the inner rod so it trace a smaller distance of rotation. Is this correct?

[image]

---

Thank you all or your superb points. I do realize this is a bit out there. The sheet as of now is a form of plastic or tarpaulin.  Having said that my requirement is to cover a circular area and while i can consider more straightforward approaches as to circumscribe the area within a square and then have straight metal rods at 90 degrees to each other - as of now i'm trying to still consider options with a circular rod.
In my hubris - i am considering the possibility of hollowing out this circular rod and having another circular rod of smaller width within it.
While the two rods do not touch, my thought is to lubricate the inside gap and have metal ball bearings that are touching the inner and outer surface of the two rods respectively. In theory i feel, perhaps now when i try to extend the sheet, instead of the larger cylinder rotating, the rotational force will transfer to the smaller balls ( that would now turn stead) and they in turn will transfer that to the inner rod that would end up turning , thereby allowing the sheet to extend, that way the only challenge remaining is of rolling the sheet onto the curved rod - i have not come across any objects that do this in real life , but i am curious to see if this can solve the conundrum.

Also is there any way for me to theoretically see if i can construct this on a software and then simulate its success ( or failure)?I am not too well versed with the recent tools and if there is anything intuitive you might know, that would be appreciated.

Comment: is what correct? ... please draw a diagram of what you are thinking

Comment: is the sheet circular?

Comment: Yes the sheet is circular . I have added an image for this to help

Comment: is this a school problem assignment? ... this can't possibly work in real life

Comment: sheet materials dont like to form double curvature. (because it means uneven stretching and uneven thickness). Which you should know if you have ever eaten a pizza slice by hand. Since the curved rod is by definition double curved you got problems. It is possible that if your material is really elastic like latex or something and you have enough even force it could work. But im not sure

Comment: @joojaa It would have to be an custom tailored elastic material with a specifically tailored gradient of elasticity across the surface in various directions, along with pre-tensioning that varies across the surface. The simulation for that seems pretty wild, and the actual manufacture of that even more so. I can't even think of how you would do that.

Comment: @joojaa Best idea I have would be to 3D print, or sequentially mask and layer a sheet with elastic, but heat-shrinkable or cross-linkable, material with varying thickness across the surface to get the distribution of elasticity required. And then heat or irradiate specific areas to effect to produce the correct pre-tension in the right places. Cross-linking via irradiating the correct areas might also be used to produce a distribution of elasticity. I suppose shrinking could also be produced by chemicals means.

Answer (score 1):

As is, this does not sound feasible with current technology. Of key importance which was not mentioned at all is what the material that the sheet is made of. Are you expecting this to completely roll up into a C shape? Or only partially into a D-shape? A C-shape is pretty much impossible and even with a D-shape it is not going to roll up cleanly, even if it were an elastic material.

There are a number of geometrical issues working against you.

1. The areas between the rod and sheet are incompatible so it will wrinkle.
2. You want to wrap the sheet around the axis of the rod, but this axis is not linear and thus varies with position, but the sheet can only wrap in a single direction.
3. The axis of the rods at the ends is nearly tangential to the nominal direction that the disc would be rolled in.
4. You want the rod to be able to roll something up, which involves the rod rolling. But the rod can't roll because each part of the rod would roll in a different direction.

What is the purpose of this device? What concessions can be made? A big problem right now is that everything is happening across each of the two primary components of your device in different directions, and that those directions are also incompatible between the two components.

Does the rod even need to be curved to begin with?

Does the rod need to be a single piece?

Does the sheet need to be a single continuous unbroken covering?

How well sealed does the sheet need to be?

Does it really need to be circular on the top-right and bottom-right?

Basically, what concessions can be made so that a feasible mechanism can be chosen to accommodate all the directions involved.

Comment: Good answer. I couldn't make any sense of what the OP was hoping to achieve with that mechanism. It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Starting the curved roller will pull the cover three ways at once.*

This can't work. A quick look at the initial roll-up conditions reveals that the cover will be pulled the same distance in three orthoganal directions.

[image]

*Figure 2. The tensions when partially rolled up.*

As the roll-up progresses more and more stretch would be required to the parts already rolled up.